# Uploading whole folder to ftp from android

Tags: android

I am ok with uploading file from android to ftp using ftp4j.
But could anyone help me with uploading all the files from the directory to the ftp.
As I said i am using ftp4j.

Comment: Why not use [list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) and then upload all those files?

Comment: sorry am newbie fr android development..could you please give me an example how to use list() to upload the files from a folder in android to ftp?

Comment: No, please do that yourself :)

Comment: No Issues , I will try by myself :)